# "How to fix onclick() that activates all buttons inside a loop

Tags: javascript, html

Im making an html where I have a couple o buttons with events attached that when triggered show text.
The problem is when clicking either of the button it only shows the text related to the first button.

```
<body>

</div>
{% if latest_question_list %}
    {% for questao in latest_question_list %}
        <p><input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" class="greybutton" value="{{ questao.questao_texto }}"/></p>
        <div id="show" style="display: none">
        <div class="aligned">
            <div id="show2" style="display: none" >
                <div class="right">
                    {% for opcao in questao.opcao_set.all %}
                       <li style="background-color: red; color: white; border: 1px solid white">{{ opcao.opcao_texto }} --
                            {{ opcao.votos }}
                            voto{{ opcao.votos|pluralize }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="aligned">
                <form action="{% url 'desporto:sondagens' %}"
                      method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% for opcao in questao.opcao_set.all %}
                        <input type="radio" name="opcao" id="opcao{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ opcao.id }}" />
                        <label for="opcao{{ forloop.counter }}"> {{ opcao.opcao_texto }} </label>
                        <br >
                    {% endfor %}
                    <p>  <input type="submit" value="Votar" class="rwbutton"> </p>
                </form>
                <p>  <input type="submit" value="Ver resultados" onclick="toogle()" class="rwbutton" /></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

{% else %}
    <div class="aligned">
        <p>Nao ha sondagens disponiveis.</p>
    </div>

{% endif %}
<br>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

js files:

```
function toogle() {
  var x = document.getElementById("show2");

  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("show");

  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

It should show each text to each button.
Anyway to do that?

Comment: Html id attribute values must be unique. You're using a loop and so you have multiple elements with the same id. You could add a CSS class and select all inputs having this class assigned.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have many elements with the same ID (`show`). Try having unique ids for each (e.g. show_0, show_1, show_2, ...) and pass an index to `myFunction()` so it knows which of these elements to get.

So, you could have:

```
<p><input type="submit" onclick="myFunction({{forloop.counter0}})" class="greybutton" value="{{ questao.questao_texto }}"/></p>
 <div id="show_{{forloop.counter0}}" style="display: none">
```

And then in your JS:

```
function myFunction(index) {
  var x = document.getElementById("show_" + index);
  //...
}
```